# Strpos with exact matches

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a function in php which I would like to perform a simple search on a string, using a kw as the search phrase, and return true if found.

This is what I have now:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($search_strings); $i++){
   $pos = strpos($search_strings[$i], $kw_to_search_for);
}
```

This works fine, and does actually find the Keyword inside the string beeing searched, but the problem is that **strpos** doesn't match exact phrases or words.

For instance, a search for **'HP'** would return true if the word **'PHP'** was in the string.

I know of **preg_split** and regular expressions which can be used to do exact matches, but in my case I don't know what the **keyword** is for every search, because the keyword is **user-inputted**.

So the keyword could be "hot-rods", "AC/DC", "Title:Subject" etc etc...
This means I cannot split the words and check them separately because I would have to use some kind of a dynamic pattern for the regex.

If anybody know of a good solution I would much appreciate it.

I mean, basically I want exact matches only, so if the KW is "Prof" then this will return true if the match in the searched string is "Prof" and doesn't have any other characters surrounding it.
For instance "Professional" would have to be FALSE.

Comment: I'm bit confused are you asking for a str comparison? You aren't asking for: `$search_strings[$i] === $kw_to_search_for` are you?

Comment: I guess I'm caught on, `...doesn't have any other characters surrounding it`. @webbiedave's solution makes sense if meant to search for a word, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use word boundaries `\b`:

```
if (preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($kw_to_search_for)."\b/i", $search_strings[$i])) {
    // found
}
```

For instance:

```
echo preg_match("/\bProfessional\b/i", 'Prof'); // 0
echo preg_match("/\bProf\b/i", 'Prof');         // 1
```

`/i` modifier makes it case insensitive.

Comment: Remember to escape / characters in `$kw_to_search_for`

Comment: @Ben: Good suggestion. I've added `preg_quote`

Comment: to prevent "preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'G'" warning 
need to use preg_quote($need_b, "/")

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to match exactly `professional` when `professional.bowler` existed in the sentence.

Where `preg_match('/\bprofessional\b/i', 'Im a professional.bowler');` returned `int(1)`.

To resolve this I resorted to arrays to find an exact word match using `isset` on the keys.

[Detection Demo](http://ideone.com/E6hszk)

```
$wordList = array_flip(explode(' ', 'Im a professional.bowler'));
var_dump(isset($wordList['professional'])); //false
var_dump(isset($wordList['professional.bowler'])); //true
```

---

The method also works for directory paths, such as when altering the php `include_path`, as opposed to using `preg_replace` which was my specific use-case.

[Replacement Demo](http://ideone.com/6xhSjB)

```
$removePath = '/path/to/exist-not' ;
$includepath = '.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/exist-not' . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/path/to/exist';
$wordsPath = str_replace(PATH_SEPARATOR, ' ', $includepath);
$result = preg_replace('/\b' . preg_quote($removePath, '/'). '\b/i', '', $wordsPath);
var_dump(str_replace(' ', PATH_SEPARATOR, $result));
//".:/path/to/exist-not:/path/to/exist"

$paths = array_flip(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includepath));
if(isset($paths[$removePath])){
    unset($paths[$removePath]);
}
$includepath = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array_flip($paths));
var_dump($includepath);
//".:/path/to/exist"
```