# Using preg_match Check IF Keyword Exists in Wordpress Post Content

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match, stripos

I am trying to figure out how I can effectively search the post content for a keyword that can be comprised of one or multiple words ( i.e. word, two words, and three words, etc. ) and retrieved using a variable ( i.e. $meta_keyword_1, $meta_keyword_2 ).

I have a function that updates custom fields based upon the results of a keyword search.  I have been successful in searching the post title for a keyword using stripos.  I was NOT able to successfully use stripos to search the post content.  I was able to research and come up with an example of a preg_match, but it keeps returning '0' or FALSE even when the exact match is present in the content.

Here are the processes within my function:

1).  Retrieve keyword and replace "-" for " " for searching purposes:

NOTE:  Meta keyword is inputted as:  word, two-words, and-three-words, blue-rabbit, red-rabbit

```
$meta_keyword_1_clean = str_replace("-", " ", $meta_keyword_1);

$meta_keyword_2_clean = str_replace("-", " ", $meta_keyword_2);
```

2).  Search IF keyword exists in post content:

```
$post_content_strip_1 = preg_match('/('.$meta_keyword_1_clean.')/', $post->post_content);

$post_content_strip_2 = preg_match('/('.$meta_keyword_2_clean.')/', $post->post_content);
```

3).  Execute IF statement if keyword exists, else continue to next IF statement if does not exist:

```
<?php

elseif ( $post_content_strip_1 !== false  ) {

    // For testing purposes, Update post meta #1 with $post_content_strip_1 value
    // Update post meta #2 with $meta_keyword_1 value

} elseif ( $post_content_strip_2 !== false ) {

    // For testing purposes, Update post meta #1 with $post_content_strip_2 value
    // Update post meta #2 with $meta_keyword_2 value

} else {

    return false;

}
```

Here are my results:

Match keywords found on post content:  word, two words

Match keywords NOT found on post content: blue rabbit, red rabbit

> a).  Using '!== false' + $meta_keyword_1 = 'word' ( MATCH ) --> First
>   IF statement executed, output '0' and 'word';
>
> b).  Using '!== false' + $meta_keyword_1 = 'two-words' ( MATCH ) -->
>   First IF statement executed, output '0' and 'two-words';
>
> c).  Using '!== false' + $meta_keyword_1 = 'blue-rabbit' ( NON-MATCH )
>   --> First IF statement executed, output '0' and 'blue-rabbit';
>
> d).  Using '!== 0' + $meta_keyword_1 = 'word' ( MATCH ) --> Second IF
>   statement executed, $meta_keyword_2 = two-words ( MATCH ), output '0'
>   and 'two-words';
>
> e).  Using '!== 0' + $meta_keyword_1 = 'blue-rabbit' ( NON-MATCH ) -->
>   Second IF statement executed, $meta_keyword_2 = red-rabbit ( NON-MATCH
>   ), output '0' and 'red-rabbit';
>
> f).  Using '=== false' + $meta_keyword_1 = 'word' ( MATCH ) --> Second
>   IF statement executed, $meta_keyword_2 = red-rabbit ( NON-MATCH ),
>   output '0' and 'red-rabbit';
>
> g).  Using '=== false' + $meta_keyword_1 = 'blue-rabbit' ( NON-MATCH )
>   --> Second IF statement executed, $meta_keyword_2 = red-rabbit ( NON-MATCH ), output '0' and 'red-rabbit';

My problems:

1).  I feel like the preg_match pattern is not properly setup to produce an accurante result of found or not-found.  My previous attempts at using preg_match would not produce a value ( i.e. 0 or 1 ), with various examples I have been able to progress it this far;

2).  My keywords are inputted as lowercase but post content could be varying.  The searches should be case insensitive, I believe that is achieved with a '/i' at the end of the pattern?;

If you think I am missing something, please let me know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE #1:**

To better illustrate my problem, I believe the reason why my keyword searches of the post content are failing is because the preg_match pattern is incorrectly setup.  The complication, including my lack of understanding, are the variable ( *$meta_keyword_1_clean or $meta_keyword_2_clean* ) that are inputted, and the modifiers that come before and after.

**This produces a FALSE result always:**

preg_match('/('.$meta_keyword_2_clean.')/', $post->post_content);

**This and variations of it produces errors:**

preg_match('/'.$meta_keyword_2_clean.'/', $post->post_content);

**I am looking for help in producing this:**

preg_match(**[something-here]**.$meta_keyword_2_clean.**[something-here]**, $post->post_content);

I hope this clarifies my need.

**UPDATE #2:**

I decided to research a little bit more on the subject after Jan's comment ( Thank You Jan! ) and I was able to find someone that asked the same question, perhaps with much better precision.  Answer to my problem here:  [Strpos with exact matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733529/strpos-with-exact-matches).  I hope this helps someone else finding this question.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve first, I am honest, I do not really know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I updated my question.  My source of concern revolves around the preg_match pattern.

Comment: I recommend you to use the plugin WordPress SEO by Yoast

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strpos with exact matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733529/strpos-with-exact-matches)