# PHP preg match exactly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I do have the following pregmatch:

```
$search = 310850;

if (preg_match("/\b$search\b/i", $response)) {
        echo "match !";
    } else {
        echo "NO MATCH";
    }
```

response contains alot of things, but it contains `310850` and also `3108502` and `31085`.

to info: $`response` contains a html page with alot of elements that contains the $`search`

How can i make sure i get a match on `310850`and not all the others?

EDIT:

How do i allow the characters `<` and `>` to be next to the search?
they could be wrapped on `ded123>number<blabla`

Comment: Don't work boundaries restrict the match to the whole word? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/N9vpPN).

Comment: It should work like that, what's the problem?

Comment: @Toto it matches all the numbers that is longer or shorter than the search word too. i dont want that

Comment: @maria: No, see [the demo](https://ideone.com/N9vpPN), `/\b310850\b/` does not match neither `3108502` nor `31085`

Comment: its html coding on my end :P @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: what's wrong with $search == $response?

Comment: cause im looking to see if what im searching for is in the $response`s html view somewhere. they could be between > and < `s

Comment: @maria https://3v4l.org/pI5ko ? Which brings me to my prev question...

Comment: $response is not an array. response is an entire html document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strpos with exact matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733529/strpos-with-exact-matches), the answer is what you are looking for then

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$search = 310850;

$responses = ["310850"," 310850 ", "0310850","3108501",

"<html>
<a href='google.com'>310850</a>
</html>
"];

function test($search, $response){
    echo $response,": ";
    if (preg_match("/([^0-9]+|^)$search([^0-9]+|$)/i", $response)) {
        echo "match !";
    } else {
        echo "NO MATCH";
    }
    echo "\n";
}

foreach($responses as $response){
    test($search, $response);
}
```

output:

```
php -q a.php
310850: match !
 310850 : match !
0310850: NO MATCH
3108501: NO MATCH
<html>
<a href='google.com'>310850</a>
</html>
: match !
```

Comment: Response is not an array, ITS an entire html page

Comment: look closer, it's set of test cases to show output for different inputs